# Calculations/unit conversion of a celestial object - Astronomy/Swift iOS

Tags: swift, astronomy

I'm developing a telescope controller open-source application. I started this project with a very little knowledge of Astronomy.
Basically, the app is going to send data to telescope over a wireless connection.

---

Data of the celestial object is as follow:

```
["SAO#": 308,
"HD": 8890,
"Con": "Alpha Ursae Minoris",
"StarName": "Polaris",
"RAH": 2,
"RAM": 31.812,
"DED": 89,
"DEM": 15.85,
"Mag": 2.02,
"PRA": 0.038,
"PDec": -0.015]
```

RAH = RA hours, RAM = RA minutes,
DED = Dec degrees, DEM = Dec minutes

(PRA and PDec are the drift of the star in arc-seconds per year (from the catalog Epoch J2000.0). I don't need to use these in the app, that I'm told.)

The controller server (data receiver) accepts in this format:
Set target RA- HH:MM:SS,
Set target Dec- DD:MM:SS,
Set target Azm- DDD:MM:SS,
Set target Alt- DD:MM:SS

---

**I would want to convert the given celestial object data to Ra, Dec, Azm, Alt.**

I'm told that:

```
RA = ((RAH + (RAM / 60.0)) * 15.0); //in degrees, RA is an earthly longitude projected onto the sky
DEC = (DED + (DEM / 60.0)); //in degrees, Dec is an earthly latitude projected onto the sky
```

For a star or other celestial object from the catalogs they have a fixed Epoch (J2000.)  I need to apply a correction for precession/nutation (wobble of the Earth's axis of rotation) to get a half decent estimate of the star's RA/Dec "now".

I'm using a [code library](http://onekiloparsec.github.io/SwiftAA/) that seems to have support for this and does the calculation on it own.
I would want to know the procedure of the data conversion from equatorial coordinates to horizontal including. 
For an instance this is how the code works:

```
    let jd = Date().julianDay
    let RAH = 2.0
    let RAM = 31.812
    let DED = 89.0
    let DEM = 15.85

    let eqCoor = EquatorialCoordinates.init(rightAscension: Hour((RAH+(RAM/60.0))*15.0), declination: (Degree(DED+(DEM/60.0))), epoch: Epoch.J2000, equinox: Equinox.standardJ2000)
    let annualAbb = eqCoor.correctedForAnnualAberration(julianDay: jd, highPrecision: true)
    let initEQ = AstronomicalObject.init(name: "Polaris", coordinates: annualAbb, julianDay: jd, highPrecision: true)
    print("EquatorialCoordinates -> RA(α):", initEQ.equatorialCoordinates.alpha, "DEC(δ):", initEQ.equatorialCoordinates.delta) 

    let userLocation = GeographicCoordinates(positivelyWestwardLongitude: Degree(.plus, 75, 51, 13.65), latitude: Degree(.plus, 30, 54, 43.55), altitude: 256)
    print("User Location -> Latitude:", userLocation.latitude, "Longitude:", userLocation.longitude)

    let preccCoor = annualAbb.precessedCoordinates(to: Equinox.standardJ2000)
    let horizontalCoor = preccCoor.makeHorizontalCoordinates(for: userLocation, at: jd)
    print("Horizontal Coordinates -> Azimuth:", horizontalCoor.azimuth.inHours, "Altitude:", horizontalCoor.altitude.inRadians.inDegrees)
```

This is the data that code returns:

```
EquatorialCoordinates -> RA(α): +37h56m06.009s DEC(δ): +89°16'05.165"
User Location -> Latitude: +30°54'43.550" Longitude: +75°51'13.650"
Horizontal Coordinates -> Azimuth: +12h1m07.396s Altitude: +30°13'16.650"
```

Here's the data from [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) according to the same location as my code.

[image]

The data calculated from my code is not even close to the one from Stellarium except apparent altitude.

Comment: Are you asking a maths question or a coding question?

Comment: @SteveO'Connor It's definitely not a code question, I added code just to show what I'm upto right now, and It's meant to be reviewed by Astronomers only. But still in case if you have used SwiftAA lib, you might be able to help.

Comment: Why don't you post this on Astronomy Stack Exchange you might have more joy

Comment: ;) I appreciate your suggestion but it makes more sense here.